# Filling a neural network with multiple values

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

According to Nvidia's neural network architecture:

```
self.model = Sequential()                                      #135, 135, 3
self.model.add(BatchNormalization(epsilon=0.001, input_shape=(135, 135, 3)))
self.model.add(Conv2D(24, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', subsample=(2, 2)))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Conv2D(36, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', subsample=(2, 2)))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Conv2D(48, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', subsample=(2, 2)))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', subsample=(1, 1)))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='valid', activation='relu', subsample=(1, 1)))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Flatten())
self.model.add(Dense(1164, activation='relu'))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
self.model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))

adam = Adam(lr=0.0001)
self.model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=adam,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This model was made specifically for autopilot problems.

At the entrance, at 1 layer of the convolutional network, it takes an image with dimensions `135, 135, 3` and at the entrance already gives out any angle that the machine should turn (depends on the dataset)

Is there any way to add along with the images - for example, any readings from the sensors? (distances, etc.)

For example: I have an image, dimension `135,135,3` as well as an array of readings from the sensor, for example:

3 any sensors
[10, 0, 25]

Well, mark them, turn left, for example.

#### -25 - to the left, 0 - straight, 25 - to the right

How can I combine readings from sensors and images so that after learning the neural network takes into account the readings of these sensors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure its possible, its just some extra data, but your processing of it might not be ideal with a Conv2D network. So maybe at the point of where you do dense or later, you merge two nets; a keras example is overhere https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26103/merging-two-different-models-in-keras its possible in tensor flow too.